# How to hide "react-bootstrap modal" form that has preventDefault() inside its onSubmit?

Tags: hide, reactjs, preventdefault, onsubmit, react-bootstrap

The problem is that when I do not use preventDefault(), page is reloaded onSubmit and hidden. When preventDefault is used my form is doing what it has in onSubmit, but it is not hiding after submit. When I use other "Close" button that has only

```
onClick={this.props.onRequestHide}
```

form is hiding just fine.

How to hide that form when it is done with its onSubmit.

```
  <Modal {...this.props} className="adressModal" bsStyle="primary" title='Adress Form' animation={false}>
    <form className="addressModal" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
      <div className="modal-body">
        <Input type="text" placeholder="Enter Kraj" className="form-control" valueLink={this.linkState('address')} ref="address" hasFeedback required/>
      </div>
      <div className="modal-footer">
      <ButtonGroup>
        <Button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.props.onRequestHide} data-dismiss="modal" active>Close</Button>
        <Button bsStyle="primary" className="btn btn-default" type="submit" disabled={this.state.isSubmitting} >Save</Button>
  </ButtonGroup>
  </div>
    </form>
</Modal>
```

Code is just mix of ModalTrigger example from
    http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals
and React basic tutorial
http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html.

Comment: Are you trying to close the modal and submit the form while staying on the same page?

Comment: It was just for clarification.  Can you post your code for `handleSubmit` and any other relevant code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just call the `this.props.onRequestHide` function inside of the `handleSubmit` function

something like this:

```
handleSubmit: function() {
  /* ... */
  this.props.onRequestHide();
  e.preventDefault();
},
```

Comment: your `this.props.onRequestHide` was missing the function call
`this.props.onRequestHide()`
working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/10370/